# Getting the true work directory when running ruby through an alias

Tags: ruby, bash

I created an alias so that I can run my ruby script from any directory.

```
alias run_me="ruby ~/mycli/script.rb"
```

However now the **File.dirname** doesn't work correctly. When my script runs from the alias, and executes `File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))`, I always get the wrong directory. I get the directory of the ruby script file but not where my terminal actually is.

---

The following code outputs `~/mycli` but I was expecting `~/some_random_directory`. How can I change this behavior?

```
cd ~/some_random_directory
run_me
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you need this? Relative paths are relative to the CWD anyway, so usually you don't actually need to know the CWD.

Comment: The reason is I want to run my ruby script from anywhere on my machine so I created an alias. However the first line of my ruby script is to loop through /tasks which is where I store all my ruby tasks. To do that, I first change directory then I run `thor` on each file. Therefore, within the task, it's not the correct directory showing.

Comment: Umm, so don't change the directory, then? It is still not quite clear to me what the actual problem is. Also, the answer you accepted does not produce the result that you say you need in your question, so that just adds to the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest:

```
File.basename(Dir.getwd)
```